# How can I change the upload directory for php on heroku to /tmp?

Tags: php, heroku

I have made a facebook app that generate dynamic images for user. the app is working fine on localhost but when i uploaded to heroku its not working.

the /tmp folder is writable on heroku, so how can i upload php files to /tmp folder?

thanks in advance

Comment: You know that with a app restart all images will be lost right? You should use some external service for hosting files, for example amazon S3

Comment: the image made will uploaded to fb user's album..so, i will not be storing the images..

Comment: @RohitAgarwal ,brother have u able to find out whats the absolute path for tmp directory in heroku??am taking images from users to process it so where that image is actaully stored??

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the tmp upload folder. Its a [php.ini option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir).

You can set it in ether your apache vhost config or in a .htaccess with;

In apache vhost;

`php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /path/to/folder`

In .htaccess;

`php_value upload_tmp_dir /path/to/folder`